# Is "test" a reserved word in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reserved-words

It'd be nice to know before I change my heuristic model to a test model, in the interests of readability.

[This page](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/test) suggests it's a reserved word, but the language there is ambigous.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Rails 3 demo app with scaffolding based on a Test model and all seemed to be working just fine, but as soon as I tried to run an Rspec test, it all fell apart, so the answer is yes, it's a reserved word.